# Rails 3 Authenticity Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html, forms-authentication, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone know how the authenticity token is managed in Ruby on Rails 3? With all the unobtrusive Javascript Ruby on Rails 3 articles showing how the HTML5 data attributes are used I don't see the authenticity token anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for you question. I was wondering if anyone knows how to configure this. Adding the token in the `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` is nice but exposes my secret when I add the file to the SCM. Can I keep it in a database or config file somewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put this in the head section of your layout file(s):

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

—which outputs:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have been using

```
token_tag
```

to add validation to custom forms without the form helper, you must now use:

```
token_tag form_authenticity_token
```

Answer (score -1):

config/initializers/secret_token.rb